# Keypad Password sequence using html

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project using Javascript and HTML and I am using a 3x3 button "keypad".

I wanted to add a secret code that would work by having the user press 4 numbers successive to each other (eg. 2301) and press the submit button, which would open up a new html page (full of settings or something). I'm making a vending machine, and am trying to add an admin access to restock the products, which will be accessed by a sequence of key presses on the number pad. This is just a little school project, so it wouldn't have to be secure, just working. I haven't attempted anything at the moment, but I want a function listening for certain presses of the keypad and as soon as a wrong number is pressed, it just resets and keeps listening (maybe by an IF command?). Then if a correct sequence of numbers are clicked, it runs a separate function which I will set up to open a window full of settings. I don't how to set this up, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a ton, Aaron.

Comment: "*I haven't attempted anything at the moment*" - well, good luck! Feel free to come back when you've attempted something, and have a specific problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is *not a "[specific programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)*, more of a request for us to do all the work.

Comment: ...I'm looking forward to know wich will be the choosen numbers for the 3x3 "keypad". Which one is out? 9? 0? 5 is the ugliest for me. Just try, maybe we could suggest something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any code/attempts so I cannot provide a 'solve all' answer. However, what I can tell you is that looking into the following will help you get to where you need to be:

1. Look into how to use an `onkeydown` function in JavaScript. This function will be called when a user presses a key on their keyboard
2. Figure out how to get the value of the key they just pressed (maybe the `onkeydown()` function will return the value of the key pressed?
3. Have your code build the 4 digit password into a string. Validate the pass code against this string.

Once you have these things down (or at least understand them) give it a try and report back for any further assistance.

Comment: Thank you for actually giving me a point to start instead of saying "Why dont you try something first". Using your advice, I ended up working something out. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Just an FYI, most stackoverflow users will downgrade your post if you do not provide any supporting evidence of research or code snippets of what you're trying to do/attempted. Please read the terms before you post. It will help you get an answer much faster.